# Show events from an iCal in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, icalendar

I'm relatively new to web programming and actually creating a new website for our local hackspace with Jekyll. The only problem I have is, that I don't know how to display the Events from our iCal calendar on a jekyll site.

Any Ideas?

Best regards
Felix

Comment: Can you post some of your code, or something you have already tried?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4672014/1015273) shows a *possible* solution. You could write a plugin that generates a JSON from your iCal file and display it on your site using jQuery.